# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0170' in position 1843: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python

I'm trying to save a dictionary in csv file. So I wrote following code in python 3.7

```
import csv
import os


with open('data_key_value.csv', 'w') as f: 
 w = csv.DictWriter(f, final_dict.keys())
 w.writeheader()
 w.writerow(final_dict)
```

But I'm getting error message

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0170' in position 1843: character maps to <undefined>
```

I have some special character in my file. I used

```
pd.read_csv(r'C:\data.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Can you suggest me how to save the dictionary

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Comment: Try writing as utf-8 as well:
with io.open('data_key_value.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:

Comment: @FranCasadome, it works.Thanks